# Creating proper model associations

Tags: ruby, model, sequel

Using the ruby [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) gem, I have a small (sqlite3) database with the following schema:

```rb
db.create_table :item_types do
  primary_key :id
  String :name, unique: true, null: false
end

db.create_table :item_values do
  primary_key :id
  String :name, unique: true, null: false
end

db.create_table :items do
  primary_key :id
  foreign_key :type, :item_types, key: :id
  foreign_key :value, :item_values, key: :id
  String :name, unique: true, null: false
  String :desc, null: false
end
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to be able to use similar to

```rb
item = Item.first(...)
puts item.type.name, item.value.name
```

Reading through the [association](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/association_basics.rdoc) guide, it looks like I need a `one_to_one` association in the `Item` model for `item_types` and `item_values`. However, I'm not sure of the proper way to link them. Should the foreign key be passed via the `key` option, or is there a more appropriate method?

Answer (score 0):

The guide illustrates setting up a one to many association with this example:

```
# Database schema:
#  artists            albums
#   :id   <----\       :id
#   :name       \----- :artist_id 
#                      :name

class Artist < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :albums
end

class Album < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :artist
end
```

To be honest I have never used Sequel but from guide it seems like you should be doing something like:

```
class ItemType < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :items
end

class ItemValue < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :items
end

class Item < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :type, class: 'ItemType', key: 'item_type_id'
  many_to_one :value, class: 'ItemValue', key: 'item_value_id'
end
```

Congratulations. You just ported the [EAV anti-pattern](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design/) to Sequel.